# How to import OEM Java lib and source into Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, import

I have done a reasonable amount of programming in various languages but I am a Java / Netbeans newbie. I have successfully created and run "Hello World" so my Netbeans installation is OK.

I want to write code to control an LED display controller card.  I have sample demo code zipped up by the OEM.  I am trying to import, run and edit that code. If I can get this running, this will be the starting point of my own code.

The zip files only include library and source files in a directory structure that does not match Netbeans.    All of my attempts to import the source and lib files have given fatal errors in Netbeans.

The directory tree has a lib and src branch at the root.  The src branch cascades 4 levels to get to the source files.

I figure if I use a different tree structure, I will need to change the import statements in the source file.  I'd rather not touch the code until I have it running.  I have tried to unzip the project tree directly into the Netbeans directory but that didn't work.

Comment: It should be enough to add the jar files to your project.  Only use the sources if you need to change the OEM lib.

Comment: I need to clarify that I have a zip file with a number of lib/ .jar files and the source for demo programs .java that use those zipped libraries.  I don't have the source code for the .jar

Comment: SOLVED:  The problem was that I pointed Netbeans to the folder that contained the .jar files.  What I didn't do was specifically select the .jar files and import those into the project.  Once I did that, all the errors disappeared and the code compiled.

Answer (score 0):

For Netbeans to be able to open a project, the folder has to contain some files that Netbeans itself generates when a project is created.

Since you only have `src` and `lib` folders available, I think the easiest solution would be to create a new project from Netbeans, so that the creation of those files is automatically managed, and then copying the content of the folders you have in the folders Netbeans will create.

You will also have to tell Netbeans to use those library, and you can do that from you new project's preferences.

**Edit**

A few more things you can try:

1. in NB, right click the folder containing the JARs you imported and select "remove", then import them back but selecting the jar files instead of the whole folder;
2. if you're not already doing so, use the "Clean and build project" button instead of "Build project";

If none of the above solve the issue, try starting from scratch again following these steps:

1. unzip your OEM files somewhere in your disk;
2. create a new empty project in NB
3. copy the files from the src OEM subfolder to src NB project subfolder
4. in NB, right click Libraries, then add JAR/Folder and select the jar files from the lib OEM subfolder

If this doesn't work either, tell me where I can find the OEM stuff and I'll try it myself :)

Comment: OK, that sounds like it should work but I cannot get it to work.  I unzipped the src and lib files into a new project directory.  This put the files in the right location.  I then created a new Java project using the "Java Project with existing sources".  This registered the src files with Netbeans but not the lib .jar files.  So I right clicked on the Netbeans "Libraries" project folder and selected "add Jar/folder" and pointed to the libs directory.  This created a NB Project Libraries sub folder with the required JAR files.

Comment: So now I have a project with the src and lib files in the right locations, and registered with NBs.  I still get the same error messages.  The compiler can't find the OEM jar files.  Clearly I am doing something wrong but I don't know what that is.

Comment: So I have looked at the import declarations in the demo source code and compared it to the OEM library.  By double clicking on the library files in NB, I can see each .class (you will know that but I have just learned).  The classes in the libraries match the import statements.  When I compile the demo code, I get a number of error messages that look like the two following comment boxes.:

Comment: D:\darren\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\onbon\src\onbon\bx06\tutorial\BxClientDemo.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
import onbon.bx06.Bx6GScreen;
  symbol:   class Bx6GScreen
  location: package onbon.bx06

Comment: D:\darren\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\onbon\src\onbon\bx06\tutorial\BxClientDemo.java:17: error: package onbon.bx06.area does not exist
import onbon.bx06.area.DateTimeBxArea;

Comment: I am wondering if there is a problem with the directory tree.  When importing into NB, there are options around relative/abosolute file paths.  Maybe if I have not done that right, NB may not be able to connect the source to the relevant library.

Comment: ....  As far as I can tell, the path and directory structure is OK.The error messages indicate that NB can't link the source to the library.

Comment: I'll take a look as soon as I can!

Comment: That would be really helpful.  I have lost count of how many times I have cleared the slate to try different things.  The link is:   http://www.onbonbx.com/softs/BX-5XX%20sdk%20EN.rar   I suspect that I am making a small but significant mistake during the import process.  I am using the BX-06 software.

Answer (score 0):

**How to import a JAR** (Java Archive, the "library" in your case) **in Netbeans:**

1. Right click on your project name, in the 'Projects' pane usually located on the left
2. Click the 'Properties' link from the pop-up menu
3. Click the 'Libraries'  link in the Categories list
4. Choose 'Add JAR/Folder', browse to your JAR and click OK

If you want Netbeans to create the JAR for the sources you have, do like Stefano says.

Comment: Followed your instructions but got the same errors.  See above comments.  Is there a NB file that has a man-readable list of objects NB can see in the OEM .JAR files?

Comment: Yes, I found the list of the contents of .Jar files.   Right mouse click on the .JAR file and select "Show Javadoc.  The OEM files came with a zipped Java Doc file.

Answer (score 0):

You should package the src folder as src.zip with a zip utility and the structure under lib with the java archiver as a jar file.

Now you can define a library in NetBeans and add these files to it (Tools => Libraries => New Library).